# I have a problem to install metasploit on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I have installed metasploit on my ubuntu 12.04 but the problem when i write

```
aboziad@aboziad:~$ msfconsole 
Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm the root which is aboziad 
and when I install bundle

```
aboziad@aboziad:~$ bundle install
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/basic.rb:336: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Bundler::GemfileNotFound
```

what is the problem please can some one help thanking your efforts

Comment: Try running `sudo gem install bundler`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
aboziad@aboziad:~$ sudo -i
root@aboziad:~# cd ..
root@aboziad:/ cd opt
root@aboziad:/opt# cd metasploit
root@aboziad:/opt/metasploit# ./msfpro
```

if it gives you an error go back and put in:

```
root@aboziad:~# sudo servcie metasploit start
```

that should fix the error bring metasploit up on the terminal